# How to stop Lambda function being triggered multiple times by a single SQS Message?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am triggering one Lambda function from another Lambda function using an SQS Message. The first Lambda function checks for changes on a webpage and if it notices any changes then it triggers an SQS message (it does not always trigger the SQS message).

*Lambda Function 1st -
Checks for changes on the webpage, if it finds changes it triggers an SQS message using the Python module boto3. This Lambda function is triggered using cron style timings*

*Lambda Function 2nd -
The SQS message (which I have called sample) triggers the second Lambda function, it also includes some data in the body with changes from the webpage that I am tracking. So as I understand it my Lambda trigger is this SQS message.*

I am currently running into an issue where (when the right conditions are met, and the SQS message is sent) the second Lambda function is queued multiple times. I am quite new to AWS and to SQS so I am not sure how to figure out why it is occurring much less to figure out how to stop it.

There are probably some important details that I need to include that I have not already, please do let me know what they might be.

Comment: So, the 1st Lambda function checks for changes in website, 
If there is any change, it sends message to SQS and 2nd lambda function is a trigger for this SQS, right ?

Comment: What is your SQS config? What are your lambda triggers? Did you analyze the logs of this lambda?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer I have added more details to the question, is that sufficient?

Comment: @FrancoMorero I am not 100% sure what to include regarding SQS config, I have looked at the Lambda logs on CloudWatch, but am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic  By queued multiple times you mean to say lambda function is triggered multiple times and you don't want multiple asynchronous invocations, right ?

Comment: By queued multiple times you mean multiples invocation with the same message or multiple lambdas running at the same time with different messages (concurrency)?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer Yeah, it is showing that it is running multiple times, sometimes up to 50 times from a single trigger. I only want it to run once when I have triggered it once. Is multiple asynchronous invocations a setting, and can I deselect it?

Comment: @FrancoMorero The message ID is different on the different log events on cloud watch, but the body of the message is the same every time

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic By seeing the logs of 1st Lambda function, can you tell me how many times it has been invoked with same message, is it exactly once with every unique message or multiple times with same message (1st lambda function)?

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic If your 1st lambda function is running exactly once with unique message everytime, check for while publishing the message to SQS is it under any loop ?

Comment: How you publish the messages? Are you using SNS? For this " Is multiple asynchronous invocations a setting, and can I deselect it?" No, SQS is async by design. You can limit the concurrency of your lambda functions

Comment: So currently the first function runs multiple times (every minute between 9 and 10 am) looking for a change in the webpage if it does not find a change then it does not send an SQS message and it returns 'No need to run next step'. If it does find a change then it sends an SQS message with the a summary of these changes in the body of the message. From looking at the log it seems that the first function only sends the SQS message once.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by how am publishing the messages? I am using SQS through the boto3 package, I have then set that same SQS message to trigger the second Lambda function

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic By publishing i mean sending the message to SQS

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic What is the size of the message that you are sending, also 
If possible, can you also include the code of 1st lambda function in question.